# What read/write speed should I expect when writing a file to unix box over cat5e cable?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, cat5e, write

Right now the read is at 40+ megabytes/second and the write is around 1.5 megabytes/second. Is that to be expected or should I do more diagnosing? It seems awfully slow...

My setup: Macbook Pro connected to LAN with cat5e. I'm writing to a dell box that has a 2tb hard drive and ubuntu server installed. The router is a D-Link Wireless AC Smartbeam 1750 Mbps Home Cloud App-Enabled Dual-Band Gigabit Router (DIR-868L). The cable from the router to the ubuntu box is 3 ft long. The cable from the router to my macbook is 30 ft long.

I'm using LAN Speed Test Lite to get my results. It basically from computer A writes to computer B then reads the file and gives you a report.

When my laptop is on wireless it will write at about .8 megabytes / sec and read at 6.5 megabytes / sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything unusually here.  A limiting factor will the hard disk on the Ubuntu server.   Once you reach this limit (appearently 1.5Mb/sec) it becomes the limiting factor on writes.  Ubuntu will cache all or part of the file in memory, so read speeds will be less dependent on disk speed.  You will likely get an increase in write speed by writing the file to a directory on `tmpfs`.  This should keep the file in memory so you don't have to deal with latency issues.

There is network and system overhead in copying a file so it is difficult to transfer a single file at the full network speed.  Wireless is half duplex and often has to share the channel with multiple devices which lowers the transfer speeds.